# Empty Excel file file returned from \t delimited string. Why is that?

Tags: php, excel, csv, export-to-excel

I am trying to echo an Excel file from a .csv string. I wrote the following:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    $buffer = $_POST['csvBuffer'];
    echo $buffer;
?>
```

`$buffer` at the moment contains a `\t` delimited string :

```
admin 2015-09-16 16:55:48 2015-09-16 16:55:48 <span class="ustatus">Active</span> Operator 
<input type="radio" name="user" id="user_1" value="1">
```

The Excel though is downloaded but contains nothing and its size on disk is 0 bytes.

Is this not the correct way to make an Excel?

Comment: It doesn't make a real BIFF-format .xls file, no! It creates  a csv/tsv file with a `.xls` extension.... but if the filesize is zero and the file is empty, then $buffer is not what you think it is.... and html markup in a csv file generally isn't a good thing either

Comment: @MarkBaker The value of the buffer is this string `admin 2015-09-16 16:55:48 2015-09-16 16:55:48 <span class="ustatus">Active</span> Operator 
<input type="radio" name="user" id="user_1" value="1">`

Comment: Then something else is very, very wrong..... but how do you know that those are the contents of $buffer? How are you debugging this?

Comment: @MarkBaker The application is running on my localhost. So, I am able to debug.

Comment: @MarkBaker Are the headers correct?

Comment: I'd use `header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0`

Comment: But all the headers do is tell the browser how to handle the data that you are sending/echoing..... the only way you can get a blank/empty file/output is if $buffer is blank/empty.... or if PHP has a major flaw that prevents echo from working (and I think other people might have noticed if that was the case)

Comment: I repeat..... how do you know that $buffer contains what you think it does? How are you debugging this? Do you have log statements in your code? Are you using browser debugging tools?

Comment: @MarkBaker I am debugging using eclipse.

Comment: The fact that you get an open/save dialogue tells you that the headers are working..... the fact that the file is empty tells you either that $buffer is empty, or that you aren't echoing $buffer

Comment: And it doesn't matter what tool you're using to debug..... it's how you're debugging that matters...... are you inspecting the content of $buffer immediately before echoing? Are you writing it to a log? Exactly how are you using that tool to be so certain that $buffer contains what you say it contains.... because the only other possible explanation is that PHP is fundamentally flawed in that `echo` does not work..... and I suspect that somebody else in the world would have noticed if that was the case

Comment: @MarkBaker The buffer is not empty, as I have already verified. The file I see is of 1KB and I now see it contains something. Seems like an encoding problem? http://s1.postimg.org/px648mkcf/Capture.png

Comment: No, this is nothing to do with encoding, it's more likely to do with the content of $buffer

Comment: if you're not checking the actual response to the browser using browser debug tools, but simply using LibreOffice to test the response, then you're not really checking..... open your output in a text editor, or use browser debug tools to look at the server response..... you said earlier that the file was empty, now you're saying that it's 1k in size.... so it's more likely that LibreOffice can't read it correctly and that $buffer contains unreadable data than that it is empty